Updating from Bionic broke apt and software updater
I recently tried to update an old system of mine running 18.04 bionic to the current release. Using the software updater there were several errors that have culminated in apt and the software updater being broken. After the software updater ran and failed I am still running 18.04.2 LTS and i cannot run any apt commands.
Has anyone ran into this?
zero@Sabertooth:~$ sudo apt update
apt: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.6.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
zero@Sabertooth:~$ sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg4.12_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.2_amd64.deb
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'libapt-pkg4.12_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.2_amd64.deb': No such file or directory

Trying a different approach using yum
zero@Sabertooth:~$ yum
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'argv'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

A full reinstallation is not desirable as I have files on one of the internal drives I dont have a large enough flash drive to save to

You have missed the boat. Since Ubuntu 18.04LTS (Bionic Beaver) became unsupported in April, 2023, Ubuntu 18.04  has passed its End-Of-Life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.  Please install to a supported release. See https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/ Your task would be made easier if /home were a seperate partition.

If you're still running Ubuntu 18.04.2 as stated; that implies you've not been applying security updates since mid-2019, with https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/08/08/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-released/ showing the ISO release date of 18.04.3 but installed systems upgraded before that date. You didn't specify what system you're asking about (Desktop, Server), but 18.04 is either EOL or EOSS depending on architecture (you didn't specify) and I'll suggest a re-install (non-destructive or not) given how long you've left your system without security fixes.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will only release-upgrade to 20.04, or the oldest supported release of Ubuntu still in standard support; you'll need many upgrades to get to the latest (three currently), where a re-install (non-destructive or not) can do it in a single step.

This system has been unused and in storage for about 5 years - i noticed the EOL statement after i tried upgrading and it had a lot of problems. However its mostly irrelevant now, the borked upgrade nerfed the machine and its toast. Needs a new install. Hopefully I can save the files since this was originally my file server and the original source of the files is lost. Thanks all

The most common cause of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' is that the original version of Python3 (including the apt module) has been replaced by a different version of Python3 (omitting the apt module).
In other words, it's usually self-inflicted. The system is running the wrong version of Python3. It doesn't do that automatically.
The typical solution is to revert to the original version of Python 3.6 that shipped with Ubuntu 18.04.
If you don't know how to do that, then borrow or otherwise obtain adequate storage to preserve your files and then reinstall.

Typically, yes it is self inflicted. That is however not the case here, jumping that many upgrades updated some modules but not others. As stated in my comment above its largely irrelevant now as the botched upgrade broke the whole OS so a new install is needed.
